# Ввести данные на сайт Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, input, site

Возникла надобность вводить данные на сайт при помощи Python 3. Смысл в чём: имеется сайт (рассмотрю на примере vk). Есть поле для ввода логина. Требуется код, который как бы будет имитировать действие пользователя, а именно: вводить в "логин" имеющийся логин и получать данные после "нажатия" на кнопку "Войти" (в итоге выведется, что мы не ввели пароль, но это для примера). Сделать нужно именно без API.
Думал сделать через парсинг, но потом осознал, что вроде бы нельзя.
Как быть?

Заранее - благодарен.

Comment: `Selenium` Вам в помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример, дальше гуглите или читайте документацию к selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get('http://www.vk.com/');
time.sleep(2)
login = driver.find_element_by_id('index_email').send_keys('your_login')
time.sleep(1)
pwd = driver.find_element_by_id('index_pass').send_keys('your_password')
time.sleep(1)
login_btn = driver.find_element_by_id('index_login_button').click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.close()
```

Comment: Премного благодарен.